# lastinsertId() AND 2nd query Insert Issue

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I've been struggling for a couple hours now. I'm creating a new user form and i need to insert data into two different, but connected tables however the code I'm here posting is not giving any errors at all, in fact it is inserting the first query(`#query1`) to the database, but not the `$query2`.

**run():**

```
public function run($query, $params = []) {

        try {
            $this->error = null;
            $res = $this->db->prepare($query);
            $res->execute($params);
            return $res;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**registerNewUser():**

```
function registerNewUser() {
        try{
            $query1 = "INSERT INTO utilizador(email, pass, dt_registo, tipo, activo) 
                          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            $res = $this->db->run($query1, [
                $this->email,
                $this->pw1,
                $this->dt_registo,
                $this->tipo,
                $this->activo
            ]);

            if(!empty($res)){
                $insertedid = $res->lastInsertId();
                $query2 ="INSERT INTO autor(nome, descricao, utilizador_id)
                            VALUES (?,?,?)";

                $res2 = $this->db->run($query2, [
                    $this->nome,
                    $this->desc,
                    $insertedid
                ]);
                if (!empty($res2)) {
                    echo 'sucesso';
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = $res2->getError();
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                // $this->errors[] = $res->getError();
                // return false;
            }               
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }    
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

It may also be important to say that I'm using jquery ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '#create-author-form', function() {
    $.post("parts/novo_autor.php", $(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data) {        
            $('#author-sucess').show();
        });
    return false;
});
```

**P.S:** Assuming the data is all OK since I'm previously passing it through another validation function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first query might be failing, since you're catching the PDOException in `run()` and than not checking the error. Remove the try/catch block from `run()` and give it another spin.

Comment: Well, I've used the `run()` loads of times, and even tried to do what you said. Still nothing, only the first query inserts data to the bd..

Answer (score 0):

Your $query2 has four question mark parameters but you are only binding three values (nome, desc, insertedid).

EDIT:
In PDO queries, the question mark parameters are placeholders that are binded with values.  The number of question mark parameters must match the number of values to be binded otherwise the query will fail as it is expecting more values.

Since it looks like you want to use 3 values, try updating your $query2 to:

```
                $query2 ="INSERT INTO autor(nome, descricao, utilizador_id)
                        VALUES (?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Will this solve the issue? Please add some example and explanation.

Comment: Sorry - first time posting on stackoverflow.  Have expanded my answer - hopefully this makes more sense now?

Comment: Unfortunately I've already noticed that and still does the same thing

Comment: Are you getting a value for the last inserted id?  Looks like you are calling lastInsertId() on the results rather than the database object handler..